# C++ vector of ofstream, how to write to one particular element

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, ofstream

To avoid continuously opening and closing multiple files that I am writing to, I am attempting to use a vector of ofstream objects. My code looks like the following so far:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<ofstream>> filelist;

void main()
{
  for(int ii=0;ii<10;ii++)
  {
     string filename = "/dev/shm/table_"+int2string(ii)+".csv";
     filelist.push_back(make_shared<ofstream>(filename.c_str()));
  }

}
```

I am using a vector of ofstream pointers because ofstream doesn't have a copy constructor. Furthermore, I'm using a shared pointer because that is supposed to be more robust against memory leaks.

The above successfully creates the files I want in the target directory. If I want to close the files, I can do something like filelist[5]->close();

The only part I'm not sure about is how I actually write to each of these files. Typically, for a single file, I do something like:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("myfile.txt");
fout<<"some text"<<endl;
```

What is the equivalent of << that I want to use in this case?

Comment: I think you want to use `unique_ptr` and not `shared_ptr` here.

Comment: Can you comment on why an unique_ptr would be better than shared_ptr in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming each pointer points to a different file stream and you don't want to have other pointers. `shared_ptr` is used when you have multiple pointers pointing to the same object.

Comment: In your current code you can do this: `filelist.push_back(filelist[0]);` which makes the pushed back pointer point at the same file stream as the first pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (auto& stream : filelist)
{
    *stream << "some text" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `(*a) << "some text"` be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You need either an `ostream` or `ostream&`.

`filelist[i]` is a `shared_ptr<ostream>` which you can in this case think of as basically an `ostream*`. This means that `*filelist[i]` gives you an `ostream&` (via the [operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%2a) overload). So, you would use something like `*filelist[i] << "some text << std::endl;`