# c++ ofstream pointer fails to write to disk

Tags: c++, pointers, flush, ofstream

I am having trouble writing to ofstream pointer and this is quite perplexing as I really don't see anything that is missing anymore. Note, this is a follow up from this question:
[C++ vector of ofstream, how to write to one particular element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737023/c-vector-of-ofstream-how-to-write-to-one-particular-element)

My code is as follows:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<ofstream>> filelist;

void main()
{
  for(int ii=0;ii<10;ii++)
  {
     string filename = "/dev/shm/table_"+int2string(ii)+".csv";
     filelist.push_back(make_shared<ofstream>(filename.c_str()));
  }

  *filelist[5]<<"some string"<<endl;
  filelist[5]->flush();
  exit(1);

}
```

This does doesn't write anything to the output file but it does create 10 empty files. Does anybody know what might possibly be wrong here?

EDIT: I ran some further tests. I let the code run without exit(1) until completion, over all files until all callbacks are finished. It turns out that some files are not empty, while others that should have data are empty.

There is plenty of disk space, and I know I have more file descriptors than are necessary for this. Any explanation for why some of the files would be written properly while others are not?

Comment: Why `std::vector<shared_ptr<ofstream>>` instead of simple `std::vector<std::ofstream>` ?

Comment: @LihO You can't copy an ofstream so you can't do a vector of ofstreams directly. Using shared_ptr instead of raw pointers saves you manually deleting resources. There are other approaches that have lower cost penalties, but for a vector of 10 items it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try: `(*filelist[5])<<"some string\n";`.

I'd guess, however, that you probably meant to write to the files inside a loop -- as-is, you're writing to only one file.

Oh, and in C++, you don't want to use `exit`.

Edit: Here's a quick (tested) standalone demo:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::ofstream *> filelist;

int main() {
  for(int ii=0;ii<3;ii++)
  {
    char *names[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
     std::string filename = "c:\\trash_";
     filename += names[ii];
     filename += ".txt";
     filelist.push_back(new std::ofstream(filename.c_str()));
  }

  for (int i=0; i<filelist.size(); i++) {
    (*filelist[i])<<"some string\n";
    filelist[i]->close();
  }
}
```

Note, however, that the file name this generates is for Windows, whereas the original was (apparently) intended for something Unix-like. For a Unix-like OS, you'll need/want a different file name string.

Comment: So I'm using exit to end execution early, is there something that should be used instead of exit? I changed to the suggestion above and it doesn't seem to change the behavior of the code unfortunately, still nothing being written.

Comment: @user788171 You're not ending execution early though.  You're at the end of `main()` already.

Comment: Well, in my contrived example, I didn't put in the rest of the code that is there after exit(), the intention is to exit execution for the purpose of this test.

Comment: Is new necessary when I push_back the ofstream?

Comment: @user788171: when you're using a shared_ptr it shouldn't be. I just used it as an easy way to get standalone code.

Comment: So I've made an edit in my original post to reflect some additional information. It turns out that when I just let the code run, some files get data written to, while other files that should get data remain empty. This is even more mysterious than before...

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the file before you call `exit` with `filelist[5]->close();`. You've aborted a process with an open file which means your write may not have made it to the OS buffer or was discarded upon process exit. You could also remove the exit call it would probably fix the problem. The results of IO on a process that is aborted are tricky to nail down, so it's best to try avoiding aborts with active IO or to assume any active IO will fail upon abort.

Comment: So I did try calling close() and that didn't change anything. Unfortunately this is inside a callback function and I'm not sure of any way to gracefully exit out of that.

Comment: @user788171 Hmm, other than file closing before exit there doesn't appear to be anything in the code you posted that suggests why you're getting that behavior. Are there special permissions on the files you're writing? Are they in a mounted directory or under a share system like afs?